# codeignter how to rewrite URL dynamically

Tags: php, codeigniter

I have category pages and subcategory pages. I want to rewrite the URL dynamically according to the category. I want to change to following url structure

sitename.com/used-cars/Audi to sitename.com/used-Audi-cars

my controller name is cars and rewrite to used-cars for now

```
$route['used-cars'] = "cars/used-cars";
```

Comment: You can try `mod rewrite`. Example : `/used-([a-zA-Z]+)-cars /used-cars/$1`

Comment: And what's your question?

Answer (score 0):

> You should try this

```
$route['used-cars/(:any)'] = 'cars';
```

Comment: i want like this sitename.com/used-cars/Audi to sitename.com/used-Audi-cars

Comment: $route['(:any)'] = 'cars';

Answer (score 0):

$route['used-cars/(:any)'] = 'cars/$1';